# No Activation Function on Output Layer for Binary Classification

Tags: neural-networks, classification, binary-data, metric

In this [pytorch example](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/22bef0517cbaf51b14428fddb2be4a49dd924609/examples/seal_link_pred.py#L192), the output layer does not have an activation function even though the neural network is being used for a binary classification task (i.e. ground truth values are either 0 = negative or 1 = positive). After inspecting the output, I can see that there are values such as -13.02 or 4.56, which are obviously not bounded between 0 and 1. Also, after adding a sigmoid activation function in myself, the performance seems to be worse than without the activation function. Thus, I have two questions:

1. Would 0 be the threshold that determines if the predicted output is the negative or positive class? In other words, is any output value $\hat{y}$, $ \hat{y}< 0$ is negative and $\hat{y}>= 0 $is positive?
2. Why does not using an activation function lead to better performance when this is a binary classification problem, not a regression problem? Is it specific to this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choosing a threshold depends on what trade-off you wish to achieve in terms of classification errors. Choosing 0 or a different number could be appropriate, depending on context.
2. [The network is trained using `BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/22bef0517cbaf51b14428fddb2be4a49dd924609/examples/seal_link_pred.py#L209), which combines the sigmoid activation and the binary cross-entropy loss into a single call. [This is described in the `pytorch` documentation.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) Combining the two operations avoids round-tripping $\exp$ and $\log$, which can cause severe loss of precision in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: I must have overlooked the BCEWithLogitsLoss, but now it makes sense. Cheers!